# If option selected, search for span containing matching text. then add HTML before span

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I am trying to add an image before a span, when an option in a form is selected.
The span and the option both have the same text value.
The name of the image is the same as the value + .png

Below is the code I have created so far, but this doesn't seem to work (no console errors though)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('#input_2_4 option:selected').each(function() {
    var name = jQuery(this).text();
    var id = jQuery(this).attr('value');
    var img = '<img src="/wp-content/uploads/artiesten_img/' + id + '.png">';
  jQuery('.search-choice span:contains(name)').each(function() {
    jQuery(img).insertBefore(this);
  });
  });
});
```

Why won't this work?

Comment: so shouldn't you be binding to the change event?

Comment: You mean adding a on change event before jQuery('#input_2_4 option:selected').each(function() { ??

Comment: Currently it only looks for the selected option on page load. I assume you want it whenever someone changes the selection. So you would need to bind a change event and call your code.